# how can I do a search filter with keyword buttons popover in React?

Tags: reactjs, searchbar

Could anyone suggest me some tutorials or some suggestion how to perform the search function using multiple popover filter button. (instead of typing input , click on the filter buttons)?

Answer (score 0):

Some think quick and easy to start to take a look and use filter and sort functions for example in a Table component could be this specific component in Ant design library`: https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-head

If you plan to implement the filter and sorter (a query to a collection of data) logic in the front-end and you plan to have multiples filters applayed at the same time you can take a look of this library: https://github.com/crcn/sift.js

If you plan to resolve the all this problems (render data, filter, pagination, sort, ...) on the server side to support lazy loding I advice you to take a look to:https://github.com/react-tools/react-table

I hope that this can help you